# Naive Bayes model using "carsmall" example data

Tags: matlab, bayesian, naivebayes

I wanna make in Matlab a Naive Bayes model with the `carsmall` data.

This is my code:

```
load carsmall
car = table(Model_Year, Weight);
naive_model = fitcnb(car, Origin)
```

But I get this error and I don't know why. Can anybody say where the error is?

> Error using ClassificationNaiveBayes/findNoDataCombos (line 256)
> A normal distribution cannot be fit for the combination of class Italy   and predictor Model_Year. The data has zero variance.

Answer (score 1):

Since the case of "Italy" appears only once there is no variance, and the normal distribution is pointless for this case. This causes the error for fitcnb, removing this element works OK.
I suggest you to organize more your code, maybe you where going to do this later but, is a good practice. So, here is the new code with a bit more of detail.

```
clear all
load carsmall
X = [Model_Year Weight];
Y = cellstr(Origin);
%The next line helps to see how many classnames you have 
tabulate(Y);
Y(36)=[]; %removing the only case of italy
X (36,:)=[];%removing the only case of italy
%Train a naive Bayes classifier. It is good practice to specify the class order.
naive_model = fitcnb(X, Y,'ClassNames',{'USA','France','Japan','Germany','Sweden'});
```